# "Deceasing" each header when converting from markdown to tex

Tags: pandoc, nbconvert

I'm using `nbconvert` (which uses `pandoc`) to convert Jupyter notebook to latex file.

`pandoc` translates markdown headers to tex sections. Is there a way to "decrease" each header in the way?

Meaning, I'd like `##` to convert to `section` instead of `subsection`, and `###` to convert to `subsection` instead of `subsubsection`.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandoc's `--top-level-division` option:

> `--top-level-division=[default|section|chapter|part]`
>
> Treat top-level headers as the given  division  type  in  LaTeX,
>   ConTeXt,  DocBook, and TEI output.  The hierarchy order is part,
>   chapter, then section; all headers are  shifted  such  that  the
>   top-level header becomes the specified type.  The default behavior
>   is to determine  the  best  division  type  via  heuristics: unless
>   other  conditions  apply,  section  is chosen. […]

So setting `--top-level-division=chapter` gives the desired behavior of converting second-level headers to sections, third-level to `subsection` etc.

Comment: I created a custom `document_contents.tplx` where `convert_pandoc('markdown-auto_identifiers+tex_math_dollars', 'json',extra_args=['--top-level-division=chapter'])`, but that doesn't seems to work.

Comment: I don't know enough about nbconvert to help there, sorry. Just make sure you are using a recent-enough pandoc version.